# Apply function to a subset of columns by factor group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling, quantile-regression

Suppose I want to apply a simple quantile regression to a subset of columns in a dataframe, by all the factor values of a column.

As an example, take mtcars.

```
data(mtcars)
cols <- c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat")
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
```

Here we take `cyl` as a factor with values 4, 6 or 8.

Now suppose I want to apply a quantile regression to each column in `cols` when `cyl == 4, 6 and 8`. I want to store the result in a list of lists:
`store <- rep(list(list()), length(cols))`
So `store` will have 4 elements, each corresponding to a column in `cols`. Going down a level, the list has 3 elements, one for each value of `cyl`. Going down another level, each element contains the results of the quantile regression.

What is the best way to do this in R? I have tried to solve this with a nested `for` loop but would prefer to avoid this if possible.

Edit:
This is my working solution, but please let me know if there is an easier method that doesn't involve using `reverseList()`

```
store <- plyr:::dlply(mtcars, "cyl", function(d) {
  lapply(d[, cols], quantile, seq(0,1,0.2))
})
store <- paleotree:::reverseList(store)
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using the `dlply` function, it seems perfectly suited for your case.

```
data(mtcars)
cols <- c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat")
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

store <- lapply( cols, function(col.name) {
    mtcars %>% select( col.name, cyl ) %>%
        dlply("cyl", function(d2) {
        quantile( d2[,col.name], seq(0,1,0.2) )
    })
})
names( store ) <- cols
```

EDIT: I updated the code to represent the problem as I understand it.

The proposed solution should give you a 4-element list, one element for each column. Then within each list element there are 3 results of `quantile` , one for each level of `cyl`

I often find it easier to look at nested lists using json:

```r
jsonlite::toJSON( store, pretty=TRUE )
```

```json
{
  "mpg": {
    "4": [21.4, 22.8, 24.4, 27.3, 30.4, 33.9],
    "6": [17.8, 18.32, 19.4, 20.48, 21, 21.4],
    "8": [10.4, 13.9, 15.04, 15.44, 16.76, 19.2]
  },
  "disp": {
    "4": [71.1, 78.7, 95.1, 120.1, 121, 146.7],
    "6": [145, 160, 163.04, 167.6, 213.52, 258],
    "8": [275.8, 290.92, 324.4, 358.2, 416, 472]
  },
  "hp": {
    "4": [52, 65, 66, 93, 97, 113],
    "6": [105, 110, 110, 117.8, 123, 175],
    "8": [150, 175, 180, 213, 245, 335]
  },
  "drat": {
    "4": [3.69, 3.77, 3.92, 4.08, 4.22, 4.93],
    "6": [2.76, 3.188, 3.732, 3.9, 3.916, 3.92],
    "8": [2.76, 3.042, 3.072, 3.15, 3.354, 4.22]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a bit stuck on the last part; how do I apply the quantile regression to all columns in cols of mtcars? 

```data(mtcars)
cols <- c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat")
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

store <- rep(list(list()), length(cols))

your.list.of.lists <- dlply( mtcars, "cyl", function(d) {
 quantile(mtcars$mpg, seq(0, 1, 0.1))
quantile(mtcars$disp, seq(0, 1, 0.1))
})```

Comment: I dont know.. O sort of got the impression you had that bit figured out and just wanted a way to create a list of lists from it. What do you want from it? Parameters? Perhaps you could create an example of what your result should looked like

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the OP to reflect my desired outcome. It should not be a huge leap but I'm a bit stuck.